# Translate months in r from Italian to English

Tags: r, date, dataframe

I'm plotting some data and I need to create a number of box-plots. The different category are months, and since I need to have them displayed in order and not into alphabetical order, I transformed the date into a factor with

```
dd.tot$month <- factor(format(dd.tot$month, "%b"), 
                       levels=format(ISOdate(2000, 1:12, 1), "%b"))
```

Since my system language (and mother tongue for that matter) is Italian, the month column in the dd.tot dataframe is in Italian. 
But I need them to use the English abbreviation (the paper is all in English and this will be the only part in Italian). 
I've tried to create a new vector with the different abbreviations to apply to the column with

```
 mymonths <- c("Jan","Feb","Mar",
               "Apr","May","Jun",
               "Jul","Aug","Sep",
               "Oct","Nov","Dec")

dd.tot$month <- mymonths[ dd.tot$month ]
```

But when I plot it with `ggplot`, they are displayed in alphabetical order. How do I translate them and have them as a factor?

Comment: Your levels have to be in the order that you want your months plotted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set the local language to English. Just type this:

```
 Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
```

Then you do not have to translate them and you can order them like this:

```
mymonths <- format(seq.Date(from = as.Date("2018-01-01"), to = as.Date("2018-12-01"), by = "m"), "%b")

dd.tot$month <- factor(format(dd.tot$month, %b), levels = mymonths)
```

If you want to put it back to Italian just type

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "Italian")
```

Comment: I've tryied... it doesn't do anything. I get a "[1] "English_United States.1252" " in response, but when I try to plot again, ggplot still uses the Italian's abbreviations for the month

Comment: you have to run the whole code again after you changed the locals

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of some data, where we fix the two problems.

```
# My data
df <- data.frame(mymonths = c("Jan","Feb", "Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"),
                 somevalue = c(1:12))

# Plotting
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(mymonths, somevalue)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

```
# Fixing order
df$mymonths <- factor(df$mymonths, levels = c("Jan","Feb", "Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"))

# Plotting
ggplot(df, aes(mymonths, somevalue)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]

```
# Fixing labels
df$mymonths <- factor(df$mymonths, 
                      levels = c("Jan","Feb", "Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"),
                      labels = c("Jan_cool","Feb_cool", "Mar_cool","Apr_cool","May_cool","Jun_cool","Jul_cool","Aug_cool","Sep_cool","Oct_cool","Nov_cool","Dec_cool"))

# Plotting
ggplot(df, aes(mymonths, somevalue)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]